# What word describes the process of a ship being slowly "swallowed" in the sea?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs, transitive-verbs

Trying to find a word which will describe the slow process of the absorption of a ship by the sea. Metaphysical words are also welcome.

> Sea water *swallowed* the ship.

Comment: You may need to add what this phrase is intended to mean, or a suitable image showing a ship being wallowed.

Comment: Looks like a typo for *walloped* to me.

Comment: Hi hrex, you need to include your research here. Please tell us what you found in the dictionary and how doesn't that help.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I would like find a word to emphasize that the ship was slowly "absorbed" or "eaten" by the sea. Like something sinking in a tar.

Comment: @TusharRaj As I understood it means the fact of being in the medium, not the process of going into it?!

Comment: @hrexen: So you're trying to find an ideal word, rather than being interested in the correct usage of `wallowed`. If that's the case, you should edit your question to specify that.

Comment: @PeterShor: Or a typo for `swallowed`. See previous comments of the OP.

Comment: @TusharRaj First I am interested in the usage of word `wallow`. And if I am using it in not a proper way, find another word that matches my description of the process. :)

Comment: _swamped_ / _engulfed_ But stylistically 'The sea gradually ... the little boat' would be better.

Comment: @hrexen: A ship wallows in water, (which is completely different than sinking). Water doesn't wallow the ship. It might, figuratively speaking, swallow the ship.

Comment: @hrexen: I suggest you hurry up and edit this to be a word request for a ship sinking slowly. Otherwise, it might get closed.

Comment: Why do you want a single word for a slow process?

Comment: Because I use it in a poem in a metaphysical meaning.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of situation in which a thesaurus shines. Look up swallowed (online or paper). Roget's is the best for abstract or metaphorical meanings (by metaphysical do you really mean philosophically?). In a poem you've written you'll have all sorts of weird constraints like meter and rhyme that are difficult to specify, but you also have the freedom to put things that are sort of 'out there' because they just sound right or are intentionally weird.

Comment: **founder**  verb    (of a ship) fill with water and sink. (Google)

Comment: I'd also note that, nautically speaking, the sea is generally treated as a living entity - so a seaman would not talk about "sea water swallowing the ship", but the floundering ship being "swallowed by the sea". A minor point, but important in the feel of such a passage. In other words, sea water may fill the ship, but she isn't claimed by the sea waters - rather by the sea.

Comment: Just as Michael says.

Comment: @Hugh That meaning seems rather obscure though.  I was certain it was a typo of "flounder" until I looked it up.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, it is a double metaphor. Ship is not a ship and sea is not a sea and nothing is "sinking". :) Maybe there is a proper term for this kind of double metaphors?!

Comment: Another word that might work here is _enveloped_, or (as Edwin Ashworth notes) better, "gradually enveloped." A somewhat creepier word choice might be _ingested_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The suggestion by Edwin Ashworth of *engulfed* gets at it. Synonyms of engulfed include swamped, submerged, submersed, immersed, innundated, consumed, overwhelmed, enveloped, swallowed up...

Online etymologies have this to say about *engulfed*:

> Late 14c., "profound depth," from Old French *golf* "a gulf, whirlpool," from Italian *golfo* "a gulf, a bay," from Late Latin *colfos*, from Greek *kolpos* "bay, gulf of the sea," earlier "trough between waves, fold of a loose garment," originally "bosom," the common notion being "curved shape."
>
> This is from PIE *kwelp- "to arch, to vault" (compare Old English hwealf, a-hwielfan "to overwhelm"). Latin *sinus* underwent the same development, being used first for "bosom," later for "gulf" (and in Medieval Latin, "hollow curve or cavity in the body"). The geographic sense "large tract of water extending into the land" (larger than a bay, smaller than a sea, but the distinction is not exact and not always observed) is in English from c. 1400, replacing Old English sæ-earm. Figurative sense of "a wide interval" is from 1550s.

My apologies for wasting an "anwer" when a comment would have been more appropriate but I'm too new to this SE to be able to comment.

Comment: this is perfectly appropriate as an answer.

Comment: Note that, though an etymology is useful for showing the history and the hidden connotations (those that currently exist but you didn't realize), it can be misleading in the sense that the current meaning has, so to speak, moved on. For example, 'tale' means a short story, but [comes from roots that mean counting](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tale&searchmode=none); seeing the etymology we think 'Ohhh... how interesting, a tale is like counting in order some events'.  But the current meaning of 'tale' has very little of 'counting by numbers in it if at all.

Comment: Anyway, good first answer.

Comment: @Mitch  I'm curious about "hidden connotations." Can you say more about how you would go about doing this? What kind of expertise is required to uncover them? What resources would you access to develop them? Is this worth posting a question on this site for wider answers?

Comment: @MikeHunter Dictionaries ostensibly define things, but they don't capture everything; take two synonyms and sometimes it is hard to objectively tell the difference but native speakers know when one is right and when the other is (eg urinate vs pee vs pass water). So reading and writing and concentrating on word usage _in context_ is what really helps. A meta question might be appropriate for more suggestions.

Comment: "this is perfectly appropriate as an answer" except it is utterly incorrect, as can be seen by using a dictionary.  the nine "ELU madness votes" are so typical of this site.

Comment: Not a waste!***

Comment: @JoeBlow Your comments seem to be a little extreme. Please show some restraint and politeness. Also, a [quick google search of dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+engulfed&oq=definition+engulfed) shows __a number of synonyms of 'engulfed' with water connotations__.

Comment: Alright.  And just as you say, you can see the meaning of engulfed very easily in a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

The word "*swallow*" might not be perfect on its own. However the verb plus adjective combination "*swallowed up*", would work just fine. Here's a quote from the  novel *Cambell's Reivers*:

> *When the misted waters swallowed up the ship and its occupants, she bowed her head and slowly returned ...*

And here's [more examples](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22+waters+swallowed+up%22)  from Googlebooks.

Answer (score 4):

> Noun   1.  foundering - (of a ship) sinking
>
> - going under
> - ship - a vessel that carries passengers or freight
> - sinking - a descent as through liquid (especially through water); "they still talk about the sinking of the Titanic"

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foundering).

Comment: I have cleared comments on this question as they had degenerated into bickering. Users are referred to our [be nice](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and [referencing](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) policies.

Answer (score 4):

If you're concerned that *swallow* is incorrect here, don't be. It's perfectly acceptable and even sees common usage. When a ship sinks on the open sea, it's often described as having been "*swallowed* by the waves", or it can be said that "the waves *swallowed* the ship". This makes sense if you imagine the sight of waves washing over a slowly descending wreck. To me, it's similar to the sight of lips closing over food, or teeth chewing.

Comment: Indeed.  or, it could be that conversely, a huge wave (perhaps) "engulfed" the boat.  this is utterly different from the ocean swallowing a sinking boat.  you might as well say that swallow (with your mouth) and lick mean the same thing.

Comment: I am concerned with swallow, as I want to emphasize the slowness of the process and how hard the ship goes down. Just imagine that something goes into tar. I am looking for a word which describes this picture.

Answer (score 2):

The word I usually use is 'sink'

Answer (score 2):

**[subsume](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/subsume)**

> Include or absorb (something) in something else

[Example](http://www.global-briefing.org/2013/10/a-tudor-tale/) (describing the sinking of Henry VIII’s vice-flagship the *Mary Rose*)

> Henry VIII, watching the battle from nearby Southsea Castle, heard the
>   screams of the drowning men as he watched the pride of his fleet being
>   subsumed by the waves.

[Another example](http://uboatsbahamas.blogspot.com/2014/04/ss-sea-thrush-sunk-by-u-505loewe-28.html) (describing the sinking of the WWII submarine, the *SS Sea Thrush*)

> Water covered her decks as far as the number two hatch, near where the
>   first torpedo struck. One can imagine the men idling nearby on the
>   still sea, watching their erstwhile home and workplace slowly – even
>   peacefully – subsumed by the sea, leaving them with an inch or less of
>   wood between them and the same fate.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is

```
"swallowed"
```

by the sea.